# Undefined control sequence for my \subsection command in my thesis

Tags: errors

I encountered a question where I cannot resolve while writing thesis:
When I use \chapter or \section, there won't be any errors; But when I write \subsection or \subsubsection, it would return error "Undefined control sequence";

Here is my main thesis.tex:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\include{thesis.preamble}
\usepackage{apalike} 
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{bm}
%\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts,style=super,nonumberlist,automake,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries



\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\coloraltlist{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3  
}




  \newcommand\bh{\tikz[remember picture]
                    \node (begin highlight) {};
                 }
  \newcommand\eh{\tikz[remember picture]
                 \node (end highlight) {};
                 \tikz[remember picture, overlay] 
                 \draw[yellow,line width=10pt,opacity=0.3] (begin highlight) -- (end
                  highlight);
                 }



\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}

\def\rotatechartwo#1{\reflectbox{#1}}


\newcommand{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\mbox{#1}}$}

% This section of packages is because of a bug with titlesec
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\parindent\z@}{\parindent\z@\leavevmode}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\noindent}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge}   
  
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
 {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
 {\thesection.}{12pt}{\Large}
   
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\sffamily\Normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{12pt}{\Normalsize}  
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\normalfont\sffamily\Normalsize\bfseries}{\Normalsize}{12pt}{}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE {\bf MY tilte }\\
 \vspace*{6mm}
}

\author{JJ}
\submitdate{June 2023}

\maketitle
\preface
\mediumlinespacing
\input{Copyright/copyright}
\input{Abstract/abstract.tex}
\input{Acknowledgements/acknowledgements}
\input{Declaration/Declaration}
%\input{quotes/quotes}

\narrowlinespacing

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0}\normalsize
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\normalsize


\mediumlinespacing

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
% \newglossaryentry{5}{name={Variation of information},description={A metric that measures the information-theoretic distance based on the similarity/dissimilarity of information between two community partitions. References to VI in this thesis  are referring to the average distance between the ensemble of partitions that are optimised by the Louvain algorithm (usually 100 optimisations)}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% All Abbreviations

\newacronym{EEG}{EEG}{Electroencephalogram}


\glsaddall
\printglossaries

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\body


\input{Introduction/introduction}

\input{Chapter 2 Methods/Chapter2 Methods}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Bibliography/PhDthesisRef}


\input{Appendix/appendix}


\end{document}
```

For the Chapters input, I have \section and \subsection commands inside, where the \subsection and \subsubsection will all have error marks on it.

For example in Introduction.tex:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}

\section{Sleep, insomnia, and its interventions}
\label{sec:Intro-Sleep}

\subsection{Sleep disturbances, cognitive decline, and neurodegeneration}
```

The \subsection will have error mark "Undefined control sequence". Although it seems to be running through as the subsection will appear in pdf.

I am happy to provide further .sty styling files if relevant, Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue!

Comment: You have `\Normalsize` (capitalized) in subsection styling. Try changing it to `\normalsize`...

Comment: We cannot compile your code since we don't have access to the file`thesis.preamble`.

Comment: Ah yes.... the \normalsize command is wrong.... Thanks a lot! My bad such simple issues!